# Is this a coordinate transfomation?

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems

Consider the redefinition $$d\zeta_1=ad\theta,~d\zeta_2=a\sin\theta d\phi$$ so that the distance between two points on the surface of a sphere of radius $a$ becomes $$dl^2=a^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2)=d\zeta_1^2+d\zeta_2^2=\delta_{ij}d\zeta_id\zeta_j$$ Can the first equation be called a coordinate transformation? Have I really transformed the line element on the surface of a sphere to Euclidean metric? But I'm told that transforming the metric tensor to $\delta_{ij}$ via a coordinate transformation is possible only for a flat surface.

Comment: If you *really* did find a coordinate transformation from $θ,φ$ to $ζ_1,  ζ_2$, why are you failing to display it?

Comment: @CosmasZachos In the first equation I displayed it. Why is this not a coordinate transformation is my question. Because they are not finite transformations?

Comment: A coordinate transformation is a map of variables, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, your redefinition, by itself, does not specify a coordinate transformation.

Assume you *did* have a coordinate transformation. Look at your conjectural $\zeta_2(\theta,\phi)$, and work out its 
$$
d\zeta_2= \frac{\partial\zeta_2}{\partial\theta}d\theta +  \frac{\partial\zeta_2}{\partial\phi}d\phi ~.
$$
Compare with your peculiar ad hoc identification,
$$
\frac{\partial\zeta_2}{\partial\theta}=0, \qquad \frac{\partial\zeta_2}{\partial\phi}=a \sin \theta.
$$
The first equation is solved by all functions of *only* $\phi$ , but the second by 
$a\phi \sin \theta + b(\theta)$, so there is no such $\zeta_2$.